# Issue with Llinear layout hierarchy and alignment

Tags: java, android, alignment, android-linearlayout, center

I've some line of code in parent XML as below:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/header_parent_layout"
            layout="@layout/common_header_layout" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/title_header_layout"
            layout="@layout/title_header_layout" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

then i have an another xml that i want to add in in LinearLayout with id:content layout in first xml inflated by below xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:customviews="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/agenday_account_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <!-- More Code -->
</FrameLayout>
```

I already set the center_vertical gravity in inflated xml layout but it's always displaying in top. Could anybody help how to treat with this.

Below code is how i add it:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.second, null);
    if (view != null) {
        mContentContainer.addView(view);
    }
```

mContentContainer is parent one.

Comment: is `mContentView` your id:content layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a gravity attribute to your `id:content LinearLayout`,so the content inside it stays centered. Like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this Idea:
Change `content LinearLayout` attributes to:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
```